# JBoss most latest and stable version

Tags: version, jboss7.x, high-availability, application-server, infinispan

I am  trying to build a highly available, scalable and performance optimistic Jboss cluster system. I will be using Infinispan subsystem for caching service.

I started off with Jboss 7.1.1 Final version but later on found that it has some really serious bugs. Also, the infinispan subsystem was not behaving as per my requirements in the same.

As of now, I need to evaluate different versions of Jboss which suffices above mentioned requirements.

Please let me know which the most stable and latest version of Jboss currently available.

Just for information, I am performing the whole stuff in Cloud (AWS).

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Application server was renamed to Wildfly, checkout its [downloads page](http://wildfly.org/downloads/). Right now it is stable 9.0.1 (I think this is using Infinispan 7.x) and unstable 10.0.0.Beta2 (I think it still uses 7.x too since Infinispan 8 was not released yet, but it's possible that version 8 will get into the final release).